# Export cells of a certain row to a .txt document

Tags: vba, excel

I got an excel document, and I am trying to get all the cells of a row into an txt document.

```
Sub ExportTxt()
    Dim CheminFichierTxt As String
    Dim Tablo() As Variant
    Dim nombreligne As Integer
    nombreligne = Sheets("Operation sab").Range("E2").Value

    Tablo = Worksheets("Génération fichier SAB").Range("E2:E" & nombreligne).Value
    CheminFichierTxt = "C:\Users\GB4678\Documents\fichier excel\fichiersab.txt"
    NumFichier = FreeFile()

    Open "C:\Users\GB4678\Documents\fichier excel\fichiersab.txt" For Output As #NumFichier

    'tu parcours le tableau
    For i = 1 To UBound(Tablo)
        For j = 1 To UBound(Tablo, 2)
            Print #NumFichier, Tablo(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    Close #NumFichier ' Ferme le fichier.

End Sub
```

But since the lines i am trying to copy are very big like this :

```
=",{

   "&$C$1&"date"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&'Création login'!$F$3&"-"&'Création login'!$E$3&"-"&'Création login'!$D$3&$C$1&",

   "&$C$1&"extraction"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&'Création login'!$F$3&"-"&'Création login'!$E$3&"-"&'Création login'!$D$3&"T15:13:24.000+0100"&$C$1&",

   "&$C$1&"description"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&A4&B4&$C$1&",

   "&$C$1&"movement"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&SI(A4="REMCBP";"credit";"debit")&$C$1&",

   "&$C$1&"currency"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"EUR"&$C$1&",

   "&$C$1&"amount"&$C$1&": "&ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(10;99)&"."&ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(10;99)&",

   "&$C$1&"status"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"posted"&$C$1&",

   "&$C$1&"custom_fields"&$C$1&": [        {
          "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"POSTING_DATE"&$C$1&",
          "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&'Création login'!$F$3&"-"&'Création login'!$E$3&"-"&'Création login'!$D$3&$C$1&"
        },{
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"FEES_NUMBER"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"0"&$C$1&"
    },
            {
          "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"LIB3"&$C$1&",
          "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"EUR"&$C$1&"
        },            {
          "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"LIB2"&$C$1&",
          "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"20,00 FR"&$C$1&"
        },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_TYPE"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&A4&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_TAG"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&B4&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_NATURE"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"CBP"&$C$1&"
    },

    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"LIB2"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"Paiement carte n°1234XXXXXX"&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"CARD_ALIAS"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&'Création login'!$C$3&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_DATE"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&'Création login'!$F$3&"-"&'Création login'!$E$3&"-"&'Création login'!$D$3&$C$1&"
    },   {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_NOM"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"Test "&A4&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_ADR"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"Vincennes"&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_CB_AVIS"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(1000000000000;9999999999999)&$C$1&"
    },    {
     "&C1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_SABID"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(1000000000000;9999999999999)&$C$1&"
    },
    {
     "&$C$1&"name"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&"TNX_CB"&$C$1&",
     "&$C$1&"value"&$C$1&": "&$C$1&ALEA.ENTRE.BORNES(1000000000000;9999999999999)&$C$1&"
    }
   ]

  }"
```

He is unable to copy them, the first three lines are well interpreted but the rest isn't and I can't figure why.
I tried many things but with some numbers or some text, this code does the job, but with these cells it always bug and it don't copy properly the cells contained in the row.

Does anybody have an idea of the reason why? Thank you in advance.

Best regards.
Madian

Comment: Where do you get an error message? At which line? You say: "The first three lines are well interpreted" do you mean that line 4 gives you the error? Is there a number greater to 2 in the cell "E2"?